# Is $F[x]/\langle x^3-1\rangle$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let F be a field.

Is $F[x]/\langle x^3-1\rangle$ a field?

I know $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. How can I use this to show the above is a field or not?

I am using the above to deduce $\langle x^3-1\rangle$ is maximal or not in $F[x]$.

Comment: Hint: If $ab = 0$ in a field, what can you say about $a$ and $b$? What does this translate to for the ideal?

Comment: Hint: $\langle x^3-1\rangle\subsetneq \langle x-1\rangle$ voids maximality of $\langle x^3-1\rangle$

Answer (score 2):

> I am using the above to deduce $\langle x^3-1\rangle$ is maximal in $F[x]$.

This is impossible. Just note that the factorization you mention gives you ideals properly containing this one. Generally, a reducible polynomial cannot yield a prime ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring $x\ne x^2 \ne x^3\ne x$ and $x$ is a cube root of $1$.  The underlying set of this "field" is $\{a+bx+cx^2 : a,b,c\in F\}$.  In this "field" we have
$$
(x-1)(x^2+x+1) = x^3 - 1 = 1-1 = 0,
$$
so we're multiplying two nonzero things and getting zero.  If you can show that that cannot happen in a field, then you have to conclude that this is not a field.

Comment: is it because $F$ is an integral domain, so $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: Can you define the field $F$ in the way you have to prove the above is not a field?

Comment: In response to your first comment: yes.  I haven't yet understood your second comment. $\qquad$

Comment: Can we let $F$ be a field as you described at the start of your answer.

Comment: There is no field satisfying the first setence in my answer.  That's what we're trying to prove here.  Essentially I've made it a proof by contradiction: we're assuming at the outset that we have such a field, and finally concluding that we don't. $\qquad$

Comment: To add to Michael's answer and comment, what does it mean for an element in a field to be (non)zero? Further, given that multiplication is associative, what can we then say about the product of two nonzero elements? Hopefully this will lead you to a (proof by) contradiction, just as Michael pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Your factorization $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ tells you that $\langle x^3-1\rangle\subseteq \langle x-1\rangle$ (which is maximal, but it's irrelevant).

The two ideals are not equal, because $x^3-1$ does not divide $x-1$.

---

Consider the evaluation map at $a\in F$, defined over polynomials:
$$
v_a\colon F[x]\to F, \qquad v_a(p)=p(a)
$$
This map is a ring homomorphism and is obviously surjective, so its kernel is a maximal ideal. Since $a$ is a root of $p\in F[x]$ if and only if $x-a$ divides $p$, we have that $\ker v_a=\langle x-a\rangle$.

Comment: under what field is the factorisation done

Comment: @joeman619 Any.